# What would be the main and essential criteria for evaluating auto-sklearn library ?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, model-evaluations, metric

I m running experiments using benchmark datasets with auto-sklearn to see how its performance is different to the standard sklearn library, Since automl does an exhaustive search over parameters and sklearn has to be manually tuned. what could be the essential criteria to judge the performance between these two libraries

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to evaluate the differences. Here are a couple:

- Performance on evaluation metric.
- Search time.